# Is there awesome_print like gem for Minitest result

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bigdecimal, minitest

I'm using `awesome_print`, because I want to see `Bigdecimal` numbers like `0.5`, instead of `<BigDecimal:7fbfdafa54c8,'0.5E0',9(18)>`.

And I also want to use same function for `Minitest` result.

Is there a gem for it?

I tried [minitest-reporters](https://github.com/kern/minitest-reporters), but apparently this gem don't change `Bigdecimal` appearance.

Comment: in rails console ?

Comment: When I run test by `bundle exec rake test`.

Answer (score 1):

Override `inspect` on `BigDecimal`:

```
class BigDecimal
  def inspect
    self.ai
  end
end
```

This is using `Kernel#ai` from awesome print (which by the way accepts accepts a handy `html: true` argument)

The reason I know `inspect` is being called by Minitest is that what you're seeing (`<BigDecimal:7fbfdafa54c8,'0.5E0',9(18)>`) is the same as what you'd see if you ran `BigDecimal.new(num).inspect`

Comment: Where can I override the method without affecting main project code? By adding `test_helper.rb`, I just got a `ArgumentError`.

Comment: you're right, my code was not correct. See the updated answer. Override `inspect`, not `to_s`